# I am trying to locate dbeaver.ini file for changing some setting in dbeaver. Any idea about the location of it in mac

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver

I want to enable jdbc tracing log to debug custom JDBC. For that I need to change setting in `"dbeaver.ini"` file. I have tried to locate it into `/Library/DBeaverData/workspace6/` didn't able to find there.

Any idea what location it can be in mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Posting it here for other people reference. I have downloaded dbeaver as application so the location is:

`/Applications/DBeaver.app/Contents/Eclipse/dbeaver.ini`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
find / -name dbeaver.ini
```